# One Windows directory, two different names

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I have a filesystem and there seems to be two different folder names for the same folder. On the DOS prompt, I don't see any directories unless I use /a.
What is going on here and how may I implement this kind of GUID/Friendly names scheme on my own?

In Windows Explorer, the folder name *looks* like E:\Mediadatabase\Storage\ but if I click in the address field, I see E:\MediaDatabase\1f9b78f5-0dcd-452a-9404-a45d0775b12f\

[Dos prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7orT.png)

[DOS prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ii7iB.png)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point or it may be a custom shell extension of some kind: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @DarkFalcon: NTFS junctions would be displayed as `<JUNCTION>`, not `<DIR>`. Could be a symlink, though. And for a normal shell namespace junction I think the dot preceding the GUID is required, as are the braces around it. The mechanism is very close to the latter here, though.

Comment: When you use /a then you'll also see hidden directory entries.  A shell extension can make a folder look however it pleases, somewhat likely for a "media database".